# Using std::regex in Windows

Tags: regex, windows, c++11

Is there any C++ compiler for windows but VS(I'd prefer something like g++) which supports C++11 std::regex?

I've tried cygwin g++, but code, that uses regex returns regex_error

Thnx a lot in advance.

Comment: GCC doesn't ship with working `<regex>`.

Comment: VS2010 has partial `std::regex` support -- what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

In general you have to specify the C++11 libraries at compile time with cygwin and g++. There's a command line parameter that lets you specify what version to use.

Comment: do you mean something like `g++ test.cpp -std=c++11 -o test.exe`? that the way i'm doing now

Comment: Yes, though it appears based on research, there is no <regex> in gcc, see R. Marinho Fernandes' post.